# When combobox changes do something ( C# )

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, textbox

I've been trying to make a program with 3 comboboxes where depending on what you pick different things happen.
Here is a screenshot of what I'm stuck with.

[image]

The only thing missing in the screenshot is the following which is in the private void Form1_Load event

cBxColor1.Items.Add("Black");

cBxColor2.Items.Add("Black");

cBxTest.Items.Add("Something");

In the screenshot above I try two methods to write something in the textbox. One whenever the text changes and then checks for the choosen item. In this case Something, Black and Black. I'm planning on adding more later but so far I'm trying to get this to work with one.

The original plan was to have while(the selected texts in the comboboxes are Something, Black and Black) then add some text to the textbox if that is true.

[image]

Screenshot of the error I get when trying the other method, I'm not sure what this means.

I've googled and searched around for a solution but I truly couldn't find anything that would help to solve my problem. I would appreciate if the 1337 hax0rz on here would help me out.

Comment: please edit your posting and place actual code not an image. makes it really difficult to read

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TextChanged is a Event. Use it in a methode like this:

```
private void ComboBox_TextUpdate(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  //Your code here
   MessageBox.Show("You are in the ComboBox.TextUpdate event.");
}
```

Add the event with += to your combobox in your initialisation:

```
ComboBox.TextUpdate += ComboBox_TextUpdate;
```

So at every TextUpdate your Methode ComboBox_TextUpdate gets called and you can code there.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using the if condition to see if the text has changed, you should use the ComboBox event SelectedValueChanged.

To create that event right-click on your ComboBox and select properties. Select "Events" and double-click the textbox next to the SelectedValueChanged event.

Then you want to check the values of each ComboBox like you did.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (cBxColor1.SelectedText.Equals("Black") || cBxColor2.SelectedText.Equals("Black") || cBxTest.SelectedText.Equals("Something"))
    {
        tbxTest.Text = "TEST";
    }
}
```

Also, that while statement is almost a death threat because once it enters that condition, it will not leave.
You won't be able to change the ComboBox value due to the while being executed.